# Google’s ability to read search history on TOR

Tags: android

I use a vpn on Android. I used it signed in to google play store when downloading TOR. My activity was switched on so now Google knows when I downloaded TOR browser:

Can Google see:

(A) My search history.
(B) A list of URLs I visited.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have Google play services installed on your Android OS: the software inventarization "feature" is not just for having a list of your programs installed - this thing is also capable of collecting crush data, so one of the leak vectors is when the Tor browser crush dump will be obtained. Another leak vector is a vendor-made backdoors that are incorporated in lots of devices like Xiaomi or in Yota. To be secure from that you need to install LineageOS or AOSP for your phone *without* google play services by transferring APK's and installing them. Tor browser's APK does not require play services at all and it can be downloaded directly